# How to increase timer while getting response from server

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

What i'm trying to do is to run a timer in the background **while getting response from server**. And if the time exceeds about 5 seconds then show some message.

I tried other timer types but couldn't figure out how to run this on a different thread.

My problem is that when it starts to execute `Subscribe()` from the client (method that is marked with *OperationContract* attribute on server side), it stops on that line of code and waits, the window freezes and after about 15 seconds only it throws *timeout exception*.

I would like to handle that exception before it fires by setting this timer, so the client also would not need to wait that long to find out the server is not running.

My code:

```
try
{
//...
   /* starting timer here */

   //my service client instance calling Subscribe method
   ServiceClientInstance.Client().Subscribe(/*username*/);

   //closing the channel
   ServiceClientInstance.Client().Close();

//...
}
catch (CommunicationObjectAbortedException)
{
   //some other operation after exception is handled
}
```

Comment: If you start your timer async, it will be hard to throw the exception in the response thread.

Comment: Which timer runs *synchronously* ?

Comment: As example dispatcher timer, Stopwatch, Dispatcher. Well at least they didn't work for me. @EZI

Comment: either start the call to the server in another thread or better use async-wcf calls

Comment: Use async method calls in WCF, and set the timeout to 5 seconds rather than manage this yourself.